# Calculating agreement between 3 users with continuous data

Tags: continuous-data, intraclass-correlation, cohens-kappa, agreement-statistics

I have a dataset of consisting of volume measurements as taken by 3 users in two trials. That is to say, each user rated each point twice, therefore I have 6 measurements in total for each point. I want to calculate agreement/consistency between the users. I'm reading about the Intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC), but one of the assumptions of the ICC is that the measurements are exchangeable, I don't think this is the case for me (since every user rated every point). Could somebody suggest an appropriate agreement metric?

Comment: Exchangeable is a generalization of independence.  So if your variables (users) can be considered as given answers that are statistically independent than you satisfy the condition of exchangeability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to incorporate the within-rater variance and the between-rater variance in a single analysis; this is the purpose of generalizability theory. However, to keep things simple for you, I would recommend starting by calculating the raters' agreement at each time point separately, thus focusing on the between-rater variance. To do so, create an item-by-rater matrix and feed this into an ICC function. Your matrix should thus have three columns and a number of rows equal to the number of "points" in your study (you didn't say how many). Repeat this process for the first and second trial separately. If you plan to use the average of all raters in your study, then use ICC(A,k) or ICC(C,k). Or if you plan to use the ratings from a single rater for each item, then use ICC(A,1) or ICC(C,1). You can find formulas and MATLAB functions for all four formulations on my [website](http://mreliability.jmgirard.com).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I have a related question; is ICC more appropriate than the concordance correlation coefficient or Kendall rank correlation coefficient? or is it even possible to say with the sparse information I provided? I have ~250 points in the study by the way.

Comment: It depends mostly on what the ratings themselves were. If you used a rating scale like 1-7 or real measurements like 5.2 cm then ICC and CCC are both appropriate. If you used rankings like first, second, third then the KRC is appropriate.

Comment: I have real measurements. Could you provide a rough idea of what information the CCC conveys that the ICC doesn't? I have a lot more reading to do, of course, but any guidance you provide would be much appreciated!